# Passing meta data / annotations to view models .Net Core Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, model

I am having trouble getting my head around the following.

I have a model in namespace Models **SalesOrder**:

```
namespace MyApplication.Models
{
public class SalesOrder
{
    [Display(Name = "Sales Order ID", Description = "The internal ID for this Sales Order")]
    [Key]
    public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Order Required Time should be a maximum of 100 characters")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Required Time", Prompt = "Enter the Time this order is required by (Optional)", Description = "The Time this order is required by the customer")]
    public string TimeRequired { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Customer Order Number should be a maximum of 100 characters")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Customer Order Number", Prompt = "Enter the Customer Order Number (Optional)", Description = "The Customer Order Number for this Order")]
    public string CustomerOrderNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Special Instructions should be a maximum of 1000 characters")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Special Instructions", Prompt = "Enter the Special Instructions for this Order (Optional)", Description = "The Special Instructions for this Order")]
    public string SpecialInstructions { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is the model used to create my tables in code first.

I then have a simplified View Model in namespace ViewModels which I use in a modal for editing / updating on a page:

```
namespace MyApplication.ViewModels
{
public class SalesOrder
{
    public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }

    public string TimeRequired { get; set; }
}
}
```

This works fine but I obviously lose the annotations for my "base class" and therefore the validation I would normally get in my view.

Am I doing things incorrectly here?

Comment: obviously in this scenario we need to duplicate the validation attributes, which defeats the purpose of using validation attribute itself (to put validation logic in one place and used everywhere). Normally you cannot avoid this kind of duplication in this scenario. For a better solution (but more complicated), with a requirement to avoid duplicating validation attributes, I would declare `interface` for both your entity model & view model. But instead of declaring a concrete class for view model, you can create it dynamically with all corresponding attributes cloned from the entity model.

Comment: that idea is really complicated because once we create the class dynamically, it should be fast. EFCore and other ORM frameworks also create proxy classes dynamically but the performance is still fast enough. So that's hard but feasible. The idea of creating the view model classes dynamically is to enable us to clone the corresponding validation attributes to those classes. I must say that it's hard and you should find some existing package for that or research existing source code doing the same things. The distance between idea and reality may be very long as in this case.

Comment: Having done some digging around, if you use the same Namespace as your base model, you can use [ModelMetadataType(typeof(Models.SalesOrder))] and the annotations are applied to matching properties. What are you thoughts on that?  It seems to work. I like keeping my ViewModels in a different namespace, however.

Comment: that's interesting but it affects your design a bit. Your `Models.SalesOrder` need to be referenced by your entity models project, which is strange because the `Models.SalesOrder` is on the view model layer. Mixing the 2 layers like that is simply a mess. That's also kind of limitation by using `ModelMetadataTypeAttribute`. It's possible that `EFCore` creates proxy classes inheriting from your entity classes ***and*** applies attributes read from `ModelMetadataTypeAttribute`. That's why it works, for other classes, it won't work.

Comment: another possible explanation for why it works is the validation process will take `ModelMetadataTypeAttribute` into consideration and read the attributes from the metadata type instead. That means the entity model classes may not have the corresponding attributes applied at all (even the proxy classes if any generated). I'm just guessing because to confirm that we need to reference the source code or play around with it by trial and error.

Comment: my final 2 cents for you is the `ModelMetadataTypeAttribute` may be recognized by model validation. So it should work for your `SalesOrder` as well (in the same way) for the same purpose of validation. I mean you can define a common interface with the corresponding properties decorated with validation attributes. That interface is in the same layer with your entity models. Now you can use `[ModelMetadataType]` on both your entity models & your view models (`SalesOrder`) with metadata type of the common interface you declare. That way you have 2 separate layers as desired.